# Can we Trigger AN with 'Active' camera object location change?

Tags: camera, animation-nodes

I want to find out a way so that the 'Object' in the trigger is Dynamic, like active camera.

I have tried 'triggers' with object location to limit 'Auto execution' to only when object is moved.

I am basically trying to make LOD system using animation-nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *Scene* trigger with the path `camera.location`.[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Oh, great! this solved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: @protonMax Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: How do I create that `Scene trigger`? I d onot see any trigger  in AN. Thanks